# cpanel notification of due time

Tags: cpanel, reseller

Suppose that I'm a host re-seller and I need the cpanel to notify me that some of my clients' host plans are due. Is there any feature in cpanel to notify me on certain dates? For example 10 days before each host plan is going to be extincted?

This is a real problem of mine. I forget to call my clients on time to extend (charge) their host plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any option in cPanel that I know of which does this. There may be a plugin but doubt it. Your best bet is to use Google Calendar and install the plugin into Chrome you can setup multiple notifications pop-up, and email as well as set it to notify you any quantity of days in advance. If you use Android your phones calendar can sync to Google so you'll be notified on your phone, email, and in your browser

** Update **
http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/whm-admin-email-notification-customers-approaching-expiry-214751.html#post887742

> Accounts created on cPanel/WHM do not expire, so there are no native
>   options available that will alert you of an approaching expiry. This
>   should be handled by a billing application. If you are looking for a
>   billing application that integrates with cPanel/WHM, you can find a
>   list at:
>
> [Application Catalog](http://applications.cpanel.net/category/billing-automation/)
>
> There are several listed under "Billing Automation", so you may be
>   able to find one that offers a more simple approach to meet your
>   needs.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: Well this is a helpful answer, thanks anagio. I should wait, there might be some plugins as you said!

Comment: @Manoochehr I updated my answer with more information on how to do this